# Is it possible to install Mountain Lion on a Mac mini that is older than 2009?

Tags: macos, system-requirements

Is it possible to install Mountain Lion on a Mac mini that is older than 2009, despite the [system requirements](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5444)?

Comment: What do you mean? And is your concern whether it's possible to make an operating system run on hardware not listed as supported, or whether it will reliably run on all the listed hardware? Also, your tags suggest you're talking about OS X Mountain Lion, but the body of the question doesn't. The answer may indeed vary whether you're talking about iOS or OS X and what version thereof.

Comment: @DanielLawson Clarified.

Comment: The linked page lists a lot of requirements, which specific one troubles you?

Comment: @patrix I want know if I can get away with installing it on a mini older than 2009. Nothing specific in mind. I'm browsing eBay.

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly to get useable answers. Otherwise it is awfully broad.

Answer (score 1):

you are lucky,  this is  mountain lion compatibility list

**Mac mini Core 2 Duo with Nvidia graphics of 2009 and later**

MacBook Core 2 Duo unibody of 2008 and later

MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo of 2007 and later

MacBook Air Core 2 Duo with Nvidia graphics 2008 and later

iMac of 2007 and later

Mac Pro of 2008 and later

Xserve Xeon Nehalem de principios de 2009.